# Email rule applied to a shared mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules, shared-mailbox

Hope I will manage to explain this clearly :) So, basically I created a rule on a shared mailbox to redirect all emails that are received to another shared mailbox.

If I understood correctly, the rules (unless they are server ones) work only when the outlook is open. the issue is that the 2nd shared mailbox where the emails are being redirected has multiple users whilst the one that has the rule is mainly used by me. I am concerned if the rule will work whilst I am on leave (the users with access to the 2nd shared mailbox do not have access to the one where the rule is applied) as I won't be able to open outlook and actually allow the emails received to be re-directed.

Any ideas on how is best to avoid this? Should I grant access to one of the users to the mailbox that has the rule? I do plan to raise a request and disable the first one and IT team to actually link/merge the mailboxes but need to move all the folders first so thought that the rule is a good workaround for the time being.

thank you guys :) (and girls!!)

Comment: First, IT can enable forwarding for you and you don’t have to worry about anything. Also, turning on forwarding is a server side rule. IT could simply add the other users to the shared mailbox as well.

Answer (score 1):

use [mail flow rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/actions?view=exchserver-2019) instead of inbox rules to redirect messages.

Comment: Can i manage mail flow rules with powershell? Samples? Anda execute rules?